# Query code shows nothing after adding a new relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I have relationship between `Student.Department` and `Departments.Id`, `Student.Faculty` and `Faculties.Id`. Below code was working before I created a new relationship between `Departments.facultyId` and `Faculties.Id`

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Students sd 
    INNER JOIN Departments dp 
        ON  sd.Department = dp.Id 
    INNER JOIN Faculties fd 
        ON sd.Faculty = fd.Id
```

Before adding `facultyId`column in `Departments` table, I could run the query, but now the query shows nothing.

Should I also write something for relationship between `fd.Id`and `dp.facultyId`?

[image: Designer]

Comment: try first if you get the students list using LEFT JOIN

Comment: I changed first `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`. I can see now everything except Department names. Everything related to Departments table returned null even I changed second `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Then you must check the information stored in your tables, `sd.Department` do not match `Departments.Id`

Comment: Okay I fixed that issue. But why should I use `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: I explain it in my answer

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, verify this join:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Students sd 
    LEFT JOIN Departments dp 
        ON  sd.Department = dp.Id
```

If cannot see Departments information, verify that sd.Department has the correct values.

Do the same with Faculties

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Students sd 
    LEFT JOIN Faculties fd 
        ON sd.facultyId = fd.Id
```

Using `LEFT JOIN` you'll see all records of the first table, and only the records of second table that match the ON clause.

And finally check the new relation:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Dapartments dp 
    LEFT JOIN Faculties fd 
        ON dp.facultyId = fd.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

I just replicate your database structure and the relationships. Your query working pretty well. If it doesn't work, make sure you have data to support your query. I mean in all tables since you are having left joins from faculty and department with student table. You can see the result for the query below.

```
SELECT * FROM student sd INNER JOIN department dp ON sd.dept = dp.id INNER JOIN faculty fd ON sd.fac = fd.id
```

[image]

Just to clarify it, I have 8 students (2 for each department), 4 facutlties (2 for each faculty) and 2 faculties. So it works. Check whether your DB has data to satisfy the query constraints.

Comment: Do I need to add `facultyId` column in `Departments` table? 
One faculty can have many departments. I thought if l would add `facultyId` and make relationship between that and `Faculties.Id`, I could see department names related to faculty names.
I thought like this because I have two comboboxes. One is for faculty, other is for departments. If I click engineering faculty name, second combobox which is for departments, is supposed to show only department names which are related to selected faculty name.

Comment: Yes it is very straight forward. The relationship is Faculty **has** Departmnet. So you need to include facultyId as foreign key in the Department table. And that should allow you to create a query to filer departments of selected faculty to a list/combobox and etc.